# How to decide what Android settings to use for Ionic deployment in Visual Studio

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have developed an Ionic app using Visual Studio. It runs in the Ripple emulator and it runs when I debug it on an Android device running version 4.4.2.

Now I want to publish the app and I am trying to follow the [Visual Studio instructions for packaging your Cordova app](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/).

My problem is that I don't know what to put into the Android settings within my config.xml for Version Code, Minimum API level, Maximum API level, and Target API level

If I look at Tools > Extensions and Updates-> Visual Studio Tools for Cordova, I can see my version is 14.0.60527.5

How do I work out what to put in the Android settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [Version Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html) for `versionCode`:

> **versionCode** — An integer used as an internal version number.

Typically, you would release the first version of your app with versionCode set to 1, then monotonically increase the value with each release. And Google Play has a upper limit for versionCode: 2100000000.

And refer to [uses-sdk](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) for min/max/target API Level:

> **API Level** is an integer value that uniquely identifies the framework API revision offered by a version of the Android platform.
>
> **android:minSdkVersion:** An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run.
>
> **android:targetSdkVersion:**
>   An integer designating the API Level that the application targets.
>
> **android:maxSdkVersion:**
>   An integer designating the maximum API Level on which the application is designed to run.

So in your case the `target API Level` should be 19(stands for 4.4.2). `Minimum API level` could be any integer below 19. `Maximum API level` could be any integer greater than 19.

Comment: Excellent information and useful links. It is possible to get quite far with Visual Studio / Ionic / Cordova before you have any need to understand the nuts and bolts of it. I'd like to add this information from the `uses-sdk` link you provided: declaring the `android:maxSdkVersion` attribute is not recommended

Comment: Also, the `android:minSdkVersion` will be dependent on the cordova plugins that are used. I have Cordova 5.4.1, which I understand supports API level 23, so I guess there is a risk if used below that, which I will need to test for if I add plugins. For that reason, I've gone with 23 as the target, 19 as the minimum